# Public Key Cryptography: Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange

Tags: diffie-hellman

Please watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QnD2c4Xovk) it's very short. If you already know cryptography and really good at it please start from 3:51.

I didn't understand the step at 4:39, can someone here to explain?

Why is $16^{54} \mod 17$ is equal to

$3 ^ {24\times54} \mod17 \equiv 1$?

He just wrote that. Alice didn't knew bob's private number how did he raised $3 ^{24}$?

Comment: It was pretty disorienting how he completely skipped over the exponentiation explanation

Comment: His newer video explained that part in great detail https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEBfamv-_do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alice didn't know that $16\equiv 3^{24}\mod 17$. The video just made it clearer that they were intrisically computing the same value.

I'm guessing that the point the video was trying to make was that 
$$3^{54\times24}\equiv3^{24\times54}\equiv 16^{54}\equiv15^{24}\equiv1\mod 17.$$

Comment: Thanks for editing question and making it look more accurate btw i got your explanation :) Thanks

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan No problem. Glad I could help!